# setting a one minute timer in JavaScript memory aid game

Tags: javascript, function, timer, counter, countdown

```
<div id="counter">1:00</div>
function countdown() {
var secs = 60;
function tick() {
    var counter = document.getElementById("counter");
    secs--;
    counter.innerHTML = "0:" + (secs < 10 ? "0" : "") + String(secs);
    if( secs > 0 ) {
        setTimeout(tick, 1000);
    } else {
        alert("Game Over");
    }
}
tick();
}

countdown(60);
```

I am having a problem with this portion of my game. I'm trying to set a 60 seconds timer for the game that starts at 60 and ends at 0, when it gets to 0 the game stops and an alert shows that the game is over.

I am very new to programming, so please give me as many feedbacks as you can. I found this code on the internet, and I figured out most of it, could you also tell me what does the tick() function do over here?

Comment: "what does the tick() function do" Given the code is nothing much more than `tick`, what do you mean by "I figured out most of it". What specifically do you need help with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way you can do it:

First declare a variable you will use for an interval (should be 'global', attached to window):

```
var countDownInterval = null;
```

Then, a function to trigger the tick interval, you should call this whenever the game is ready to start:

```
function startCountDown()
{
    countDownInterval = setInterval(tick,1000); //sets an interval with a pointer to the tick function, called every 1000ms
}
```

which will call the tick function every second:

```
function tick()
{
    // Check to see if the counter has been initialized
    if ( typeof countDownInterval.counter == 'undefined' )
    {
        // It has not... perform the initialization
        countDownInterval.counter = 0; //or 60 and countdown to 0
    }
    else
    {
        countDownInterval.counter++; //or --
    }


    console.log(countDownInterval.counter); //You can always check out your count @ the log console.

    //Update your html/css/images/anything you need to do, e.g. show the count.

    if(60<= countDownInterval.counter) //if limit has been reached
    {
        stopGame(); //function which will clear the interval and do whatever else you need to do.
    }

}
```

and then the function where you can do everything you need to do after game has finished:

```
function stopGame()
{
    clearInterval(countDownInterval);//Stops the interval
    //Then do anything else you want to do, call game over functions, etc.
}
```

You can fire up the counter at any time by calling `startCountDown();`

Answer (score 0):

Pseudo code of tick:

```
function tick() {
   reduce counter variable;
   if counter > 0
      wait for 1 second;  (This is what setTimeout(tick, 1000) means)
      call tick() again (recursively)
   }
   else {
     game over
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
var countdown = function(sec, tick, done) {
    var interval = setInterval(function(){
        if(sec <= 0) {
            clearInterval(interval);
            done();
        } else {
            tick(sec)
            sec--;
        }
    }, 1000)
}

countdown(10, console.log, function(){console.log('done')})
```